# CFT partition function from OPE

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I always hear that the spectrum(conformal dimension) of a CFT together with the OPE(operator product expansion) data completely define the CFT. I'm curious about the relation between these two data. More specifically, is it possible to obtain CFT spectrum if we know all the OPE data? If so, are there specific functions (e.g. in 2d CFT) to relate them, in the sense that {h1,h2,h3...}=F[c111,c112,c123, ...]. It's enough to provide me with some nice references. Thanks!

Comment: An easier question is how to construct partition function (on torus) from three point functions on sphere. We can think of the three point function as a Riemann surface with three legs (punctures). Then I tried to glue some of them to obtain a torus. A difficulty is that by doing this I can only get a closed surface with genus larger or equal to 2. Maybe the torus partition function can be obtained when one of the moduli circle becomes degenerate.

Comment: When someone says the spectrum and OPE coefficients together determine a CFT, why would you take this to mean that the spectrum determines the OPE coefficients?